# Counting Duplicate Values In Multidimension Array of Objects

Tags: php, laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent, duplicates

I have a multidimensional array objects $all2[$i][$j] which is undefined but received through my laravel sql query request:

```
for($i=0; $i<(count($all));$i++){
            $uID = HashtagFollow::select('user_id')->where('hashtag_id', $all[$i]->hashtag_id)->where('user_id', '!=', $loggedin->id)->get();

    for($j=0;$j<count($uID);$j++){
$all2[$i][$j] = HashtagFollow::select('hashtag_id')->where('user_id', $uID[$j]->user_id)->whereNotIn('hashtag_id', $all)->orderBy('hashtag_id')->get();
}
}
```

which gives the following output:

```
0: [[{hashtag_id: 5}], [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}], [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 13}]]
    0: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    1: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    2: [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 13}]

1: [[{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}], [{hashtag_id: 5}], [{hashtag_id: 5}],…]
    0: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    1: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    2: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    3: [{hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]

2: [[{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}], [{hashtag_id: 5}], [{hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]]
    0: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    1: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    2: [{hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]

3: [[{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}], [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}],…]
    0: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    1: [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    2: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    3: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    4: [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    5: [{hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]

4: [[{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}], [{hashtag_id: 5}], [{hashtag_id: 5}],…]
    0: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    1: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    2: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    3: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    4: [{hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]

5: [[{hashtag_id: 5}], [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}],…]
    0: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    1: [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    2: [{hashtag_id: 5}, {hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    3: [{hashtag_id: 5}]
    4: [{hashtag_id: 2}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
    5: [{hashtag_id: 12}, {hashtag_id: 13}]
```

I am now trying to loop this this array of objects and count how much of each hashtag_id there is.

expected output: 
hashtag_id:2 count: 2
hashtag_id:5 count: 5
hashtag_id:12 count: 3
hashtag_id:13 count: 6

Comment: How are you getting those expected counts? For hashtag_id:2, there are 3 groups that contain that hashtag_id, and there are a total of 5 across all groups. Where did you get count: 2?

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to count?

Comment: @newUserName02 they are coming from my database my sql query is a loop. it loops through each user in my array $uID and gives me their hashtag_ids. and count: 2 is what i want returned i want it to read through my dimensional array $all2 and tell me how many of each hashtag_id: 2, 5, 12, 13 are present in the new array and give me a count for each one.

Comment: and i know what they expected counts are because ive added them up already so i know what to be expecting @newUserName02

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider querying directly for these counts.

e.g.

`SELECT hashtag_id, user_id, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM HashtagFollow 
GROUP BY hashtag_id, user_id;`